# 3 divs, main div as image, 1 overlay title - top, the other overlay description bottom JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, slide

I have a sample image of what the inital stage must be:

[image]

As you can see I have the main image inside a div as the background: width and height 100%

The title div - an overlay over the image div at the top

And the descsription div - another overlay over the image div at the bottom

What I am looking for is: once I hover over any part of the iamge is, the title div slides up out of view and the description div slides down out of view.

Has anyone come across a solution to this structure of jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a little jsfiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/A2E2n/

The jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#img").hover(
      function () {
      $("#title").animate({"top":"-50px"},500);
      $("#desc").animate({"bottom":"-50px"},500);
  },
  function () {
      $("#title").animate({"top":"0px"},500);
      $("#desc").animate({"bottom":"0px"},500);
  }
  );

});
```